# Wrong Page Path displayed in Google Analytics

Tags: url, google-analytics, analytics

So I noticed GA displays urls this way :

Main Page : **/www.example.fr**  instead of **/**

Content page : **/content-page/www.example.fr**  instead of **/content-page/**

The domain is added after the page path.
And of course, visualizing the page leads to a 404 error as this specific page path does not exist.

What can cause this ?

Site running WordPress with **Yoast plugin.**
Data retrieved with **GTM**.

- Can it be on SEO plugin sending wrong information ?
- An option in GA ?

I never saw that before.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your problem is because you specified a default page in your view settings.

Go into Analytics > Admin > View Settings > Default page and if there is a url value remove it and save.

This should fix your issue.